# stretch image using canvas android

Tags: java, android, image, bitmap, android-canvas

Hello I have two images and i am merging that images using canvas

here is the below code

```
      Intent intent = getIntent();

       //bm is the image get from camera
        bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(intent.getStringExtra("getdata"));

       //this is simple white text image
        bm1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.txt_made_hawk_nelson);
        imgSeletedPhoto = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgSelectedPhoto);

        int width = bm.getWidth();
        int height = bm.getHeight();

        int maxWidth = (width > bm1.getWidth() ? width : bm1.getWidth());
        int maxHeight = (height > bm1.getHeight() ? height : bm1.getHeight());


        // calculate the scale - in this case = 0.4f
        float scaleWidth = ((float) maxWidth) / width;
        float scaleHeight = ((float) maxHeight) / height;

        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);          
    bmOverlay = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, true);

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmOverlay);
    //canvas.drawBitmap(bm, 0, 0, null);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bm1, 0, 50, null);
    imgSeletedPhoto.setImageBitmap(bmOverlay);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

i want to scale image and image should look like below

[image]

but instead of by doing above code it is looking like

[image]

XML code of this file is

```
         <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="10" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="7" >   // this is covering 70% of screen

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgSelectedPhoto"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="3"
    android:background="#baca9d"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp" >
```

can any body help me how to **stretch image and make it full from bottom and top side also and put text in center**

Comment: What height you really want for your bitmap ?

Comment: I am editing my question the (bitmap size loads screen size's 70 % area

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
int targetWidth  = 70% of screen width;
int targetHeight = 70% of screen height;

int saclex = (int)((float)targetWidth / (float)bmp1.getWidth());
int sacley = (int)((float)targetHeight / (float)bmp1.getHeight());
```

apply scale values to bmp1 and create scaled bitmap

```
saclex = (int)((float)targetWidth / (float)bmp.getWidth());
sacley = (int)((float)targetHeight / (float)bmp.getHeight());
```

apply scale values bmp and create scaled bitmap. Hope this will help. or else you can use this method to create it.

```
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(mTargetImage, bWidth,
                bHeight, false);
```

Comment: ya i have done as u suggested and it is perfect fine from top and bottom but now it is not covering full area from width side :(